# htaccess rewrite for language subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, languages

I need to point subdomains like `es.domain.com` to `/public/www/index.php`
The problem is my host does NOT provide me to set a path, I can only set up the subdomains for "local use", which creates the folders in the `public` directory

My structure is

```
/public/
/public/de/
/public/es/
/public/it/
/public/www/index.php
```

My host told me to use .htaccess files inside the sub domain folders.

I tried, for example in `/public/es/` something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(de|es|it)\.mydomain\.com$
        # Create an environment variable to remember the language:
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
        # Now check if the LANGUAGE is empty (= doesn't exist)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} !^$
        # If so, create the default language (=es):
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
        # Change the root folder of the spanish language:
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^es$
        # Change the root folder:
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php
</IfModule>
```

But I am getting a 404 on this:
The requested URL /public/www/index.php was not found on this server.

In my DNS list I see that
`es.domain.com` CNAME `onlinux-it.setupdns.net`
while
`www.domain.com` CNAME `domain.com`

I tried also assigning
`es.domain.com` CNAME to `domain.com`
but that did not change anything.

Comment: Thank you for using my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531002/htaccess-rewrite-for-language-subdomains/9635159#9635159, this is a great reward that what I write isn't useless ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to change the `DocumentRoot` directive in your Apache config files for those sobdomains so that they all point to `/public/www/` but I guess you can't do that.

I don't think there's any way to do what you are asking with a `.htaccess` file.

You could create a symlink instead of a folder so that:

```
/public/de/ -> /public/www/
```

Are you able to do that?

Comment: hi, no I can't. No symlinks either, I tried that allready making them with PHP's `symlink()` function but it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, I think you might be best off going for a subdirectory such as `/es/` or a query string such as `?lang=es` instead of subdomains.  If you want to be clever, you can use the client's `Accept-Language` header to choose the best language for them.

Comment: That's what I have right now, with a `?locale=es_ES` var, but I need to solution with the subdomains for SEO and Analytics. `/es/` directories are too difficult to implement right now.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> In my DNS list I see that `es.domain.com` CNAME `onlinux-it.setupdns.net` while `www.domain.com` CNAME `domain.com`

Maybe the problem is about your DNS configuration.

My own DNS configuration is something like:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA dnsxx.ovh.net. tech.ovh.net. (2011111300 86400 3600 3600000 86400)
            IN  NS     dnsxx.ovh.net. 
            IN  NS     nsxx.ovh.net. 
            IN  A      123.123.123.123 
*           IN  CNAME  papdevis.fr.
```

This means "if you type `papdevis.fr` or whatever behind i.e. `www.papdevis.fr` or `olivier.papdevis.fr` go to the server at the adress `123.123.123.123`.

If I change the adress `123.123.123.123` to a new one for example `234.234.234.234`, this will work and as soon as you'll type `papdevis.fr` or any other stuff (like explained before) it will go to `234.234.234.234`. Everything will work smoothlessly without touching any `.htaccess` file.

So try to apply the same DNS configuration on your site.